# Codeigniter output filename in zip and rar file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I seen **zipArchive** class, but I don't know how to apply it in CodeIgniter.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tools extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    //$this->load->library('zip');

    $path = base_url()."files/2016_02_26_02_03_26_Philosophizing_and_Being_Human_TB.rar";
    $zip = new ZipArchive; 
    if ($zip->open($path)) 
    { 
         for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
         {   
              echo 'Filename: ' . $zip->getNameIndex($i) . '<br />'; 
         } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
         echo 'Error reading zip-archive!'; 
    } 
}
}
```

Is there any library in CodeIgniter that can output all file names inside the compressed file?

Comment: show your code what you tried so far

Comment: please see the updated question, thanks sir

Comment: Given answer is correct, I'd like only to point your mistake. You should manage path of file (with zip class) instead of url. `FCPATH` is equivalent path to `base_url()` location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following code to accomplish this task. You should use `RarArchive` class instead of what are using now. Because your file in not zip but `.rar`

```
   $rar_arch = RarArchive::open('./files/2016_02_26_02_03_26_Philosophizing_and_Being_Human_TB.rar');
    if ($rar_arch === FALSE)
        die("Could not open RAR archive.");

    $rar_entries = $rar_arch->getEntries();
    if ($rar_entries === FALSE)
        die("Could not retrieve entries.");

    //echo "Found " . count($rar_entries) . " entries.\n";

    foreach ($rar_entries as $e) {
        echo $e.'<br/>';
        //echo "\n";
    }
    $rar_arch->close();
```

But before this make sure your `RarArchive` extension is installed in your server. For checking whether it is enabled, you may use `phpinfo()` and search `RAR support`

For ZIP use this

```
$zip = new ZipArchive; 
        if ($zip->open('./files/2016_02_26_02_03_26_Philosophizing_and_Being_Human_TB.zip') == TRUE) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
                $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
                echo $filename.'<br/>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check now `.zip` file solution given too

Comment: im sorry sir but i dont have enough reputation to accept your answer